# How to find if nodes are running on the same machine?

Tags: ros, rosnode, rosmaster, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone!
I see ROS is a real distributed system, all nodes use node_name and node_uri to identify itself.
Now I need to write a monitor process, to monitor all nodes on the same machine.

From http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Slave_API, I can use getPid( ) to get the PID of that node server.
But how can I check if that node is running on the same machine ?
Is there a standard way of doing this ?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285515/how-to-find-if-nodes-are-running-on-the-same-machine?/) by [zcm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33932/zcm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2018-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosnode machine` will list the machines (ie: hosts) that the master knows about, and `rosnode machine <hostname>` will list all nodes that run on a particular machine (ie: hostname).

As for how to do this with the Master API, take a look at how `rosnode` does this internally, specifically the `get_machines_by_nodes()` and `get_nodes_by_machine()` methods ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/94aaaec56e51840d8a39de383c6e89054af97e1e/tools/rosnode/src/rosnode/__init__.py#L143-L221)).

If you're going to be using this often, consider that these methods incur quite some overhead:

> This is a very costly procedure as it must do N lookups with the Master, where N is the number of nodes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zcm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33932/zcm/) on 2018-03-15**:
Thanks!
I think Master get this hostname from every node's node_uri,  if the hostname is unique for each machine,
and each machine only use one hostname, then I think this approach is correct.